# How to use WHERE & AND in MySQL query and Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Good morning, I have a table in my MySQL workbench schema as shown below and I'm running the query direct from workbench:
`SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE date ='2021-11-05' AND patient_id = 260939631 LIMIT 4;`

```
     # patient_id,   voltage,     time,         date
    '260939631',    '98',       '18:51:46',    '2021-11-13'
    '260939631',    '98',       '18:51:47',    '2021-11-13'
    '260939631',    '111',      '18:51:48',    '2021-11-13'
    '260939631',    '106',      '18:51:49',    '2021-11-13'
    '260939631',    '115',      '18:51:50',    '2021-11-13'
    '260939631',    '114',      '18:51:51',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '5',        '18:57:32',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '317',      '18:57:33',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '321',      '18:57:34',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '325',      '18:57:34',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '328',      '18:57:35',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '337',      '18:57:35',    '2021-11-13'
```

The output is okay just like am expecting

```
     # patient_id,   voltage,     time,         date
    '785393661',    '317',      '18:57:33',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '321',      '18:57:34',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '325',      '18:57:34',    '2021-11-13'
    '785393661',    '328',      '18:57:35',    '2021-11-13'
```

Now I want to run the same query using Tkinter GUI where the user has to enter the date and the LIMIT, this is the query have come up with:

```
  def analyze_voltage_time():
    lim = limit_var.get()
    start = s_date_var.get()
    end = e_date_var.get()
    _id = id_selector.get()
    pat_id = _id[:9]
    query = "SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE date = "+start +" AND patient_id ="+pat_id + " LIMIT  "+lim
    mycursor.execute(query)
    result = mycursor .fetchall()
    voltage, time = list(zip(*result))
    for volts in voltage:
        voltage_container.append(volts)
    for tim in time:
        time_container.append(str(tim))                        
    my_ax1.plot(time_container, voltage_container)        
    my_canvas1.draw_idle()
    analyse_btn['state'] = DISABLED
```

when I run am getting the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 513, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(query,
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND patient_id =785393661 LIMIT' at line 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\Desktop\Level 5\18136709_BIT_280_Arduino_ECG_Project\18136709_ECG_LArdmon_APP_Final.py", line 260, in analyze_voltage_time
    mycursor.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 269, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "C:\Users\Kennedy Mulenga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 518, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND patient_id =785393661 LIMIT' at line 1
```

Is there something am not doing right?

Comment: Follow a tutorial and update the code to use parameters for all data positions — this will make the code more readable, more secure, and avoids trivial errors with queries. The error is likely to the *left* of 'AND' in the generated string. For example, I suspect the string might look like `.. WHERE date = AND participant_id =785..`.

Comment: In any case, viewing the *actual* string sent to MySQL will clearly show where the query is bad. The “debugging details” involve identifying (and showing) this value.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missed  the quote around the date value but anyway you should avoid string concatenation in query code - use parameters instead (and use var for limit only or for a full parametric query use a procedure)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT voltage, time FROM patient_results_tbl WHERE date = %s AND patient_id = %s LIMIT " + lim , (start,pat_id))
```

Comment: `%s` is used as placeholder for MySQL, not `?`.

Comment: @acw1668  .. answer updated ..